# How to set Default Web Browser, Mail Client, Video Player & Music Player in the system

Tags: 11.10, default-programs

I am trying to find the option that sets, for the whole system the default Web Browser, Mail Client, Video Player and Music Player instead of having to do it for each type of file. I knew where the option was in 11.04 but somehow I can not find it again.

Just to not get anymore confused I am not talking about right clicking a file then changing the "Open With" to the one I want. The option I am looking for affects everything in general, so if I change, for example, the default video player to VLC, all movies will be watched with VLC.

I am using Unity.

Comment: You are correct foss. I did not find it and let me tell you I looked a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open the session menu (top-right gear) and go to `System Settings`.
2. Go to System Information (should be in the last row - System)
3. Select `Default Applications`